# bootstrap Carousel not working in homepage in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

Using WordPress, I have a page with a carousel with the following code:

```html
<div class="swiper-container services-slider swiper-container-horizontal" data-cols="3" data-autoplay="1">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
    <article id="post-5854" class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-active" data-mh="ltx-services" style="width: 370px; height: 687.391px; margin-right: 30px;">
```

however this is not autoplaying in homepage [Homepage](http://yantraev.com), I copied this section in a test page and checked and its working fine [test page](http://yantraev.com/test/)

can anyone please tell me what could be wrong here, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your console using developer tools, you will see that you have quite a couple of errors, and one of them is related to the carousel script `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'slidesPerView' of undefined` .. I suggest that you start by sorting out all the errors including the related one. :-)

Comment: am new to javascript sir, i only know Wordpress, can u please tell me how to fix this error?

Comment: As I said you need to start looking at all the errors in the console, they also tells you that there is a lot of conflicts, I would start by removing all JS plugins that you do not need (you have a lot on the site, which also makes a poor load time) and also make sure that the JS files are loaded in the correct order.

Comment: i will check and get back to you sir